# Getting all possible values of parameter ($par) in Optim() function

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am using the optim function in R, which gives result for only one value in range given (lower and upper limits), but the problem is I need all the parameter values from 0.3 to 20 and their values for a plot. Is that possible? The code and result is given below?

```
n <- 20
b0<-b1<-1
x <- rnorm(n)
e <- rnorm(n)
y = b0+b1*x+e

wts <- rep(1,n)
mod <- lm(y~x,weights=wts)
SS <- mad(mod$resid)
err <- mod$resid/sqrt(SS)



optim(par =  3, fn = tau.hat.beta.Qader, x = err,lower = .3, upper=20,method = "Brent")
```

$par
[1] 20

$value
[1] -0.5698667

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve], in particular show us the definition of `tau.hat.beta.Qader`?

Comment: You can use any function like x^2 or something

Comment: Please edit your question to include the function ...

Comment: OK, but it will help greatly if you give us the function rather than having us make it up.  That's what a [mcve] is ...

Answer (score 1):

`optim()` minimises a function, in your case `tau.hat.beta.Qader`. You give it an interval, in which you assume the optimum to be.

If you want the values of the function for given values of its parameter, try the following:

```
vals <- data.frame(par = seq(from = 0.3, to = 20, by = 0.1), f = NA)
vals$f <- tau.hat.beta.Qader(vals$par)
```

`optim()` produced corner solution, the parameter for which the function is minimised is the upper bound of the interval. This is often the case if the true (or global) optimum is outside the provided interval.

Comment: Whatever you are doing is different from what OP is asking. Imagine you have the y values, you need the x values that result to the y values that you have. OP needs to plot a graph whereby they have the y-values and do not have the x-values. On the other hand, you have given an example whereby you have the x-values.

Comment: Then I misunderstood the question. Re-labelling as x and y is misleading, I think, as OP has variables x and y in their question. Rereading the question, I think OP may be looking for a grid expanding parameter values against values of `err` (the second input to the target function), filled with function values.